# Extracting a .tar file and creating a filelist

Tags: string, shell, unix, substring, filelist

i have this little code here

```
     for file in *.tar.gz;
     do tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}";
     done
```

It extracts a tar.gz and deletes it. Now I have to create a filelist file (.fl) named like a substring from the .tar . For example, I have to delete the first 5 letters and the last 5 (the extension) from the name of the .tar.gz . And that for every .tar.gz that I extract.

Example:

- I have a ABC_A.tar.gz with a ABC_A.xml in it.
- I have to make a A.fl
  and in that A.fl i have to write ABC_A.xml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, you can do the following for each file:

```
# delete first five characters
name=${file:5}

# delete .tar.gz suffix
name=${file%%.tar.gz}
```

Comment: Hi, the script doesn't catch the first part of the code name=${file:5}. Also, I have to dynamicaly generete the .fl files (for every .tar.gz a single .fl file)

Comment: Use `${file:4}` if you want to delete the first 4 letters. Then, in your loop, run `tar tfz "$file" > "${name}.fl"` to output the list of files present in the tar.gz.

Comment: I managed to solve it, thank you guys for your answers. 
    `for file in *.tar.gz; 
    do tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}";
    tmp=${file:39} && b=${tmp%.tar.gz*} && echo "${file%.tar.gz*}.xml" >> "${b}".fl;
    done`

Comment: @tljubas, you should _accept_ (the check-mark besides the answer) an answer and/or _upvote_ (the upwards triangle above the counter) one you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
for file in *.tar.gz
do
    # this creates the file list into a .fl file:
    tar tfz "${file}" > "${file:5:-5}.fl"
    # this extracts and afterwards removes the tar archive:
    tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}"
done
```

You also can combine the two in one step:

```
for file in *.tar.gz
do
    tar xzvf "${file}" > "${file:5:-5}.fl" && rm "${file}"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for the try but I've tried it and it doesn't work. Maybe I have implemented it wrong? for file in *.tar.gz; do tar xzvf "${file}" && rm "${file}" > "${file:5:-5}.fl"

Comment: That's not what I wrote :-)

Comment: I extended my solution by the `for` loop of yours from the question.  What you wrote in your comment would have just redirected the output of `rm` into a new file for each tar (so empty files are created).  Notice that I'm using `t` instead of `x` as tar-command to list the contents instead of extracting the tar.